# JavaScript: How to copy all properties of Object to a Class variables?

Tags: javascript, class, object

I want to transfer object's properties to a class' variables. For example:

```js
const obj = {
    a: 1,
    b: 'hey',
}

class TestClass {
    constructor(parentObject) {

        // I need: this = parentObject, this.a must refers to parentObject.a, this.b = parentObject.b ...
        ...

    }
}

const aClassObj = new TestClass(obj);
console.log(aClassObj.a); // should return 1
```

**I don't want** to make them equal in every line for example:

```js
this.a = parentObject.a
this.b = parentObject.b
```

---

Whatever in `parentObject` must be in `this`.

Thanks!

Comment: `Object.assign(this, parentObject)` should do the trick.

Comment: you can use Object.assign(this, parentObject)

Comment: @ambianBeing No. You can't assign `this` to anything by using `=`.

Comment: @MaheerAli Right! `this` is reserved in JS. Can't assign like that.

Comment: I have tried assign `this` with `=` but it didn't work, so I asked this question. Object.assign() is the one I've searched for! Thanks all of you for your helpful comments :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can merge the object with the `this` reference using [**Object.assign()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

```js
const obj = {a: 1,b: 'hey'}

class TestClass {
    constructor(parentObject) {
        Object.assign(this, obj)
    }
}

const aClassObj = new TestClass(obj);
console.log(aClassObj.a);
```